# Create Auto email validation

Tags: javascript, html, email

I've got a website where people can download a trial version of some software. They have to enter their e-mail address but can get away with typing in anything as long as it has an '@' and a .com/.co.uk etc. Because I want to use these addresses to send information about the full product to, I'm trying to find a way to send a validation email to the new user before they can download the software. (that way i know the email is valid) I've been searching Google for ages and can't find anything of the sort to help me. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What server are you running? You cannot send an email from the user's browser using HTML5 and Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like an activation email (activation link) and after that redirect user to your download page.

old school solution:
you can try:

```
$token = md5(uniqid(time()));
```

and then:

```
<?
// some more code... after submitting your form:

$headers="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $headers.="Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
                $headers.= "From: your site<noreply@site.com>\r\n";
                   $content="
                   <html>
                        <head></head>
                            <body>
                                <p>activation link</p>
                                <p>click here to activate your account: <br /> <br /><a href=http://site.com/index.php?go=yourscript&active=".$token.">LINK</a></p>";
                        mail($email, "activation link", $content, $headers);
                    print"<div style='padding: 20px;'>
                            <p>check your email!</p>
                        </div>";
                    }   
?>
```

inside of yourscript.php simply grab a token and update your data base marking this email address as an active one.

something like:

```
 // some more code...
elseif($_GET["active"])
        {
           mysql_query("UPDATE Lorem SET active=1 WHERE token='$_GET[active]'");
           if(mysql_affected_rows()==1)
                {
                         print"success.";
                 }
                 else
                 {
                          print"error !.";
                  }
        }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do, Could you point me in te right direction for making this happen?

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for your help. Can you just clairfy what the \r\n does please?

Comment: Line endings should always be \r\n in mail headers and content.

Comment: thanks again, it's not an easy thing to find out how to do on the interweb